# Notation for an event $A_i$ in which the $i$th flip is head (encoded as 1) (The experiment is: 10 coin flips in a row)

Tags: probability, notation

This is a problem I made up, because I want to know the notation.

If the first of ten coin flips results in head (head encoded as 1) then the event $A_1 = \left\{ (1,s_2,...,s_{10}) : s_j \in  \left\{ 0,1 \right\} \text{for } 2 \le j \le 10  \right\}$ said to occur. If the $i$th coin flip is head, what is the notation for $A_i$ ?

If there are different ways, please write them.

My suggestion is

$A_i = \left\{ (s_1,...,s_{10}) : s_i = 1 \text{ and } s_j \in  \left\{ 0,1 \right\} \text{for } 1 \le j \le 10 \text{ and } i \ne j \right\}$

Comment: That's fine and all... but this is one of those situations where using words is probably much better than using symbols.

Comment: A somewhat more compact notation for  your $\ A_i\ $ is
$$
\left\{\left.s\in\{0,1\}^{10}\right|\,s_i=1\right\}
$$

Comment: what does to the power of 10 mean?

Comment: @Xenusi\begin{align}
 \{0,1\}^{10} & \stackrel{\text{Def}}{=}\underbrace{\{0,1\}\times \{0,1\}\times\dots\times \{0,1\}}_\text{10 factors}\\&=\left\{\left(s_1,s_2, \dots, s_{10}\right)\left|\,s_i\in \{0,1\}\ \text{for } i=1,2,\dots10\right.\right\}\\
\end{align}